# Django contentType and read only database

Tags: django

a newbie question

I have a Django project with two applications `core` and `nagios` each with its model

I have two database connections `default` and `nagios`

The nagios database is read only

when I use `python manage.py syncdb` this error appears

```
Table 'nagios.django_content_type' doesn't exist"
```

why does the contentType application need to create a content_type table in the nagios database?
and
how can I force the contentType application to check against the default database connection only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to set up an [automatic database router](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing).